# Internet Explorer bugs

Tags: html, internet-explorer

i having trouble with IE browser... i got all working itill i tried check explorer lol.

Anyway, i want to create fixed position top menu but IE got diffrent margin then moizila or any other advanced browser.

```
    <center>
        <div class="header-line">
          <ul id="navigation">
             <li><a href="forum.php" class="a1">Soldier Of Fortune 2</a></li>
             <li><font style="color: #464545">|</font></li><li><a href="forum.php" class="a2">Index</a></li>
             <li><font style="color: #464545">|</font></li>
             <li><a href="members.php" class="a2">Members</a></li>
             <li><font style="color: #464545">|</font></li>
             <li><a href="download.php" class="a2">Downloads</a></li>
             <li><font style="color: #464545">|</font></li>
             <li><a href="tutorials.php" class="a2">Tutorials</a></li>
             <div class="header-line1">
                <li>
                  <a class="a" href="profile.php" title="View Profile">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li><font style="color: #464545">|</font></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
             </div>
          </ul>
        </center>

.header-line1 {
    position:fixed;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 1100px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2c2a2a), to(#131010));
    /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2c2a2a, #131010);
    /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#2c2a2a, endColorstr=#131010);
    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#2c2a2a, endColorstr=#131010)";
}
```

Thanks to all helpers

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid.

An unordered list (`ul`) may only contain list items (`li`) as their first descendant. A `font`-tag or a `div` container can not be parented to the `ul` directly, but you may place them in an `li`.

Also make sure all your elements are correctly closed. You have an unclosed `div`.

If your HTML is not valid, you get strange results. Fix your validation first, and see if that helps.